# In Selenium how to check that on clicking an element we have actually moved to another page?

Tags: selenium, automation

The scenarios is when you click on submit button on page A, it redirects you to Page B most of the time but there are some conditions when it will take back you to Page A without going to Page B.

Also, there can be frontend validation errors which sometimes prevent the submit button to take control to the next page.

So I exactly want to verify that when I clicked on submit button it has taken me to Page B or if page A is displayed again it is not because of validation errors but it is the fresh page came after redirection.

Comment: What are the changes within the WebPage/DOM, when 1) From `Page A` directed to `Page B` and 2) `Page A` gets refreshed?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your URL get changes after click on submit button If Yes the you can use below code

```
String currentPage=driver.getCurrentUrl();

driver.findElement(By.yourLocatorForSubmitButton).click();

String newPage = driver.getCurrentUrl();
if(currentPage.equals(newPage))
{
    System.out.println("On Same Page");
    // Here you perform your further action if there is some validation error then get those validation and fullfill the condition
}
else
{
    //carry on your further action comes on new page
}
```

Comment: The comparison may be more complicated than what you have here. Some sites will add URL parameters for various reasons including error states. If this doesn't work, you may want to investigate looking for a page name, e.g. login.aspx, or some other substring in the URL instead of a full URL comparison.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to make sure that we have successfully navigated to page B after clicking submit button in page A:

1. By checking the existence of any locator(Usually title of the page or buttons) of page B after clicking submit button on page A.(recommended)
   *Selection of locator should works in all circumstances
2. Check for change in URL.(Less preferable )

Comment: Why is checking for a change in URL not recommended?

Comment: @JeffC, Not recommended because it's depends on the application, some application wont redirect/reload until the complete submission of form. In such cases URL would remain same. suppose lets take an example of user creation and first page would be entering personal info and second would be like educational details and after few pages submit button will be there. URL will remain same until click on submit.

Comment: That really depends on the site though. Some sites are like that but many (I would say most) are not. In that case I wouldn't say it's not recommended, it would be more like it won't work. You can't determine page change by URL if the URL never changes.

Comment: @JeffC, yes there is an uncertainty and i am changing not recommended to less preferable though

Answer (score 0):

1.Check for the change in the url of the page.
2.Compare the content of the page before and after clicking the submit button.